# Intimacy of the hour?

Tags: phrases

This following snippet is from [The Art of Power by Jon Meacham](https://books.google.fr/books?id=oeFUTfvFquEC&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=he%20was%20suffering%20from%20his%20headache%20as%20the%20candle%20burned%20down%20and%20jupiter&source=bl&ots=bFDy1rpIIS&sig=dqUjr8qQP9SnMxamVTDBLYt77Xs&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=he%20was%20suffering%20from%20his%20headache%20as%20the%20candle%20burned%20down%20and%20jupiter&f=false), a biography on Thomas Jefferson,

> It was nearing midnight as he wrote these words. He was suffering from his headache as the candle burned down and Jupiter, his personal slave, fell asleep. Perhaps it was the ***intimacy of the hour*** that encouraged his candor; perhaps he was boasting vainly. But Jefferson had some reason to say that “providence” had given men like himself the “means” to satisfy his sexual appetites—means he appears to have made use of.

I was wondering about the meaning of 'intimacy' in this context. From my search, the closest fitting meaning comes from Oxford Dictionary, defined as "A cosy and private or relaxed atmosphere". Could it be the right way to understand the phrase in this context?

Comment: You got it right. Midnight is dark and quiet and private. It feels as if the walls of the world have closed around you. Sounds are muffled, lights are muted, you're typically alone, in your private room or chambers, with nothing but your thoughts. It's a very intimate time.

Comment: One might ask why you think the definition you found might *not* fit. But I'm not sure doing that will add anything.

Comment: Hey Clara, it may sounds odd to you, but as a non-native speaker, I feel when applied with this meaning, it should collocate with someplace or someone, like 'intimacy of the room or my family'. I can't really get it when it's followed by a specific time. I'm not sure if I get myself understood. :)

Comment: @Shun You are perfectly clear :)  Think of the night enclosing you, enveloping you, as a soft, dark cloth draped over the world. The hour is *intimate*.

Comment: Just to add to the other (excellent) comments, "hour" can also be taken to mean "situation" - so it's not really about any specific time as such: he is describing how he felt at that *moment*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. "The cosy and private or relaxed atmosphere of near-midnight" seems to be exactly what the phrase is saying.

To borrow from @Dan Bron's comments:
"Think of the night enclosing you, enveloping you, as a soft, dark cloth draped over the world." And: "Sounds are muffled, lights are muted, you're typically alone, in your private room or chambers, with nothing but your thoughts. It's a very intimate time."